# manage hls native behaviour in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmlhttprequest, http-live-streaming

I have created a video serving service, in my application is use hls format for videos and for playing videos i use flowplayer.

the problem i faced is that in my m3u8 files, i have this url for first part of ts file.

```
http://****/videos/2017/9/39594b34-e06e-415b-a176-c6971fe28190/b7f1d54e-4543-4852-9fbe-75693c2bfe58-3600.ts
```

here is my html configuration for flowplayer

```
<div id="hlsjsvod">
```

and here is my javascript configuration for flowplayer

```
flowplayer("#hlsjsvod", {
    splash: true,
    aspectRatio: "16:9",
    clip: {
        // enable hlsjs in desktop Safari for manual quality selection
        // CAVEAT: may cause decoding problems with some streams!
        hlsjs: {
            safari: true,
            xhrSetup: function (xhr, url) {
                 url.replace("http","https")
            }
        },
        sources: [
            {
                type: "application/x-mpegurl",
                src: "http://****/videos/2017/8/a9b68f36-c229-47c9-850d-0af298692693/348b790b-0cc1-4817-b846-acef88f1067b-master.m3u8"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

what is want to be able to do is change http for ts files to http;

as you can see in the code above i can change it through xhrsetup.

every thing is good until i want to access xhrsetup in ios , iphones. because iphone use native hls , it does not go through my xhrsetup code in ios, i want to be able to do this in ios too.

does any one have any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

That's simply not possible.

Safari on macOS provides the [MediaSource Extension (MSE)](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/) which players like [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) or [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/video-player/) can use to play HLS using Javascript instead of the native HLS playback of Safari.

Safari on iOS [does not provide the MSE](http://caniuse.com/#search=Mediasource). As a consequence, ever HLS player has to use Safari's native HLS playback, which simply doesn't provide ways to interfere with the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it .
This option is not available.