# How to select HLS video quality with javascript in iOS/Safari?

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am making Hls video player by using `Hls.js` library and add a function to select video quality. My problem is that Safari on iOS does not support `Hls.js`. I know it can be used only the browser supporting MSE. And i also know the library is not needed on iOS/Safari because `video` tag supports Hls basically on Safari. I can make Hls player just by using  `video` tag without Hls library, but i can not put the function to select video quality. `video` tag does not support quality selector.

How can i make video quality selector for iOS/Safari?
Youtube supports that even though the browser is Safari on iOS. I believe there must be a way. anyone help please!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible.

See [this comment](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/pull/2954#issuecomment-670021358) which I think suggests that it is not possible to have manual quality selection and access to metadata and manifest tag attributes when using the browser's native HLS implementation (i.e. without HLS.js).

Also see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/4727#issuecomment-1151439985).

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779621/795016) to a similar question.

For reference, also see [Embedding HLS.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js#embedding-hlsjs) in the official docs.