# How to manage quality in video HLS in iOS/Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, http-live-streaming

I have made a player with hls.js in web but when integrating it in a webview in flutter I have problems to handle the different qualities of the video in safari iOS. This is because Hls.isSupported() is false. So I have to use the native browser to play the .m3u8 file with the video tag.

The issue is that I can't handle the different qualities that I have in the playlist (.m3u8). There must be some way to handle such qualities in safari or iOS because youtube does allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible.

See [this comment](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/pull/2954#issuecomment-670021358) which I think suggests that it is not possible to have manual quality selection and access to metadata and manifest tag attributes when using the browser's native HLS implementation (i.e. without HLS.js).

Also see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/4727#issuecomment-1151439985).

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779621/795016) to a similar question.

For reference, also see [Embedding HLS.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js#embedding-hlsjs) in the official docs.